# How to model schema with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I have two models, `Group` and `User`. A user can create many groups and is then the owner of those groups. Other users can join those groups and therefore become members of those groups.

My question now is how to model this with Ruby on Rails.

I have created a `join` table between `Group` and `Users` and I added a reference from `Group` to the owner (foreign id to user).

Note: not sure if I did all this correctly.

Here are the attributes I currently have in `Group` and `User` (I don't know how to access the `join` table, so I can't show it to you).

Group: `id`, `topic`, `home_town`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `user_id`

`user_id` was added with the following migration and I want it to reference the owner:

```
class AddOwnerReferenceToGroup < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :groups, :user, index: true
  end
end
```

User: `id`, `name`, `email`, `password_digest`, `remember_token`, `created_at`, `updated_at`

As for the relationships, here's what each class contains:

User  -> `has_many :groups`

Group -> `has_many :users`

Is it possible (and do I have) to add a `belongs_to` relationship in the group class to reference to the owner?

Comment: You can do a simple `belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'` (implied foreign key would be `owner_id`) in the Group model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set it up like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_users, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_users
  has_many :owned_groups, :through => :group_users, :class_name => "Group",  :conditions => ["group_users.owner = ?", true]
  ...
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_users, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :group_users

  def owner
    self.users.find(:first, :conditions => ["group_users.owner = ?", true])
  end

  def owner=(user)
    if gu = self.group_users.find_by_user_id(user.id)
      gu.update_attributes(:owner => true)
    else
      self.group_users.create(:user_id => user, :owner => true)
    end
  end
  ...
end

#group_users table has fields user_id, group_id, owner(bool)
class GroupUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user

  after_save :enforce_single_owner

  def enforce_single_owner
    if self.changes["owner"] && self.owner
      GroupUser.find(:all, :conditions => ["group_id = ? and id <> ? and owner = ?", self.group_id, self.id, true]).each{|gu| gu.update_attributes(:owner => false)
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

In this schema, the join table model has responsibility for tracking which of the members of the group is the owner of the group.  A group has many users, and one of those wil be the owner.

Comment: Can you provide the code I should use to create this joinTable? I used rails g migration createJoinTableGroupUser :groups :users, and got a migration that creates a table with two strings, one :User and the other :Group. I renamed it to group_users, and I can't figure out where the file is. Unlike Group and User it's not in 'models' folder.

Comment: `rails g migration` doesn't create the model for you.  You can do that yourself.  As for the migration, just write your own, you don't need to use `rails g` for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible and you should.

By adding to your Group

```
belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
```

you can model your requirement that a group is created by one of the users.

In my snippet I used an arbitrary name in `belongs_to` just to make the code more readable. You don't have to but it definitely clears up things. The downside is that `ActiveRecord` cannot guess to which class you refer when using custom association names, thus, you need to manually specify it.

In a similar fashion you could change `has_many :users` to

```
has_many :members, class_name: 'User'
```

Whatever feels more natural when you read your code.